# How to increase the length of a sequence of numbers in vector

Tags: c++, r

I'm trying to make a rewrite the following lines of code of R in C++

```
if (l > length(a)) {
  a <- c(a, a + a[length(a)])
}
```

Here a is a sequence and l is an integer. I just want to check if l is out of index of a (i.e. a[l] is not defined), and if so I want to extend the vector by concatenating it with a + a[length(a)].

In C++ I have:

```
if (l >= a.size()) {
  a.resize(2*a.size());

}
```

Here I have '>=' since indices start from 0, but I'm not sure how to initialise my new values.

As an example if a = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3) and l = 4, then I want to change a to

```
a = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, (0.1+0.3), (0.2+0.3), (0.3+0.3)) 
  = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
```

Comment: `vector` resizes automatically if you `push_back` or `emplace_back` elements to it

Answer (score 2):

```
auto size = a.size();
if (l >= size) {
    auto last = a.back();
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        a.push_back(a[i] + last);
}
```

Something like the above? Tons of variations on this are possible.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the possibility that `l` is larger than `size() * 2`:

```
while(l >= a.size()) { // loop until l < s.size()
    size_t elements = a.size();
    auto last_element = a.back();
    for(size_t e = 0; e < elements; ++e)
        a.push_back(a[e] + last_element);
}
```